# Covering space, second-countable

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let $p:Y\to X$ be a covering space and $p^{-1}(x)$ countable for every $x\in X$
>
> Show, that if $X$ is second-countable, so is $Y$

Hello,

I am a little bit stuck with this question, because I do not really know, how to involve the fact, that $p$ is a covering space.
Could you give me a hint on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to somehow define a countable base for the topology on $Y$ using the fact that you know $X$ has a countable base. How might one associate to an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ an at most countable number of neighbourhoods of points in $Y$?

Comment: Ok, I know that I have an open set in $X$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$. Than we can note $p^{-1}(U)\subseteq Y$ as union of open sets $S_i$ which are maped homemorph onto $U$.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done without a paracompactness or local compactness condition, there's probably some slick proof that doesn't need it, but not the one that's coming to mind. The usual condition is that for all $x \in X$ we have that there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U_x) \cong U_x \times D$ where D is some discrete set. With paracompactness you can construct an open cover of these sets that's countably infinite and then use that finite cartesian product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Duh, I see how to do it, will write an answer.

Comment: That would be great.